# Boot time program running on virtual computer without OS

Tags: nasm

For school assignment I have to write a program described below and I would really like some help on how to approach this problem. To be clear, I don't want you to solve this, I just want some guidance on how to do it.

Problem:

Write a boot time program, which will be run in a virtual computer without an operating system. The program has to print out your name and the words "ALT key is pressed" or "ALT key is not pressed" according to status of the ALT key.

Additional hints:
- the program has to be written in 16 bit mode

- compiled program including its data must be less than 510 bytes in size
- directive "org 0x7c00" specifies the correct address in the memory where the program is loaded
- write instructions before the data
- program should execute in an endless loop
- there is no printf function, you will have to use interrupt 0x10
- to read the state of the alt keys you can use the interrupt 0x16
- to position the output of text use interrupt 0x10
- binary format of the executable should be "bin" (nasm -f bin -o boot.bin code.asm)
- resize the binary file to the size of a floppy disk (truncate -s 1474560 boot.bin )
- mark the binary file as bootable disk: at location 0x1FE save the value 0x55 and at 
  location 0x1FF save value 0xAA (use hexadecimal editor, for example: ghex2)
- start the virtual machine with your binary file as a floppy disk: (nice -n 19 qemu -fda boot.bin)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you have that is working, and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: You've been given a lot of hints and guidance here. About the only thing left is to get on and write the code. I don't see what more help we can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Bootloaders) on assembly bootloaders. Taken from that article, here is hello world -

```
        org 7C00h

        jmp short Start ;Jump over the data (the 'short' keyword makes the jmp instruction smaller)

Msg:    db "Hello World! "
EndMsg:

Start:  mov bx, 000Fh   ;Page 0, colour attribute 15 (white) for the int 10 calls below
        mov cx, 1       ;We will want to write 1 character
        xor dx, dx      ;Start at top left corner
        mov ds, dx      ;Ensure ds = 0 (to let us load the message)
        cld             ;Ensure direction flag is cleared (for LODSB)

Print:  mov si, Msg     ;Loads the address of the first byte of the message, 7C02h in this case

                        ;PC BIOS Interrupt 10 Subfunction 2 - Set cursor position
                        ;AH = 2
Char:   mov ah, 2       ;BH = page, DH = row, DL = column
        int 10h
        lodsb           ;Load a byte of the message into AL.
                        ;Remember that DS is 0 and SI holds the
                        ;offset of one of the bytes of the message.

                        ;PC BIOS Interrupt 10 Subfunction 9 - Write character and colour
                        ;AH = 9
        mov ah, 9       ;BH = page, AL = character, BL = attribute, CX = character count
        int 10h

        inc dl          ;Advance cursor

        cmp dl, 80      ;Wrap around edge of screen if necessary
        jne Skip
        xor dl, dl
        inc dh

        cmp dh, 25      ;Wrap around bottom of screen if necessary
        jne Skip
        xor dh, dh

Skip:   cmp si, EndMsg  ;If we're not at end of message,
        jne Char        ;continue loading characters
        jmp Print       ;otherwise restart from the beginning of the message


times 0200h - 2 - ($ - $$)  db 0    ;Zerofill up to 510 bytes

        dw 0AA55h       ;Boot Sector signature

;OPTIONAL:
;To zerofill up to the size of a standard 1.44MB, 3.5" floppy disk
;times 1474560 - ($ - $$) db 0
```